# How long to roast pistachios

Tags: roasting

If my home roasted pistachios are not crunchy, do they need to roast longer or at a higher degree?  I did 15 minutes at 300.

Answer (score 2):

Never go by time when roasting nuts.  Always go by smell.

When you smell toasted nuts, get them off the heat *immediately*, and out of the hot pan.

Comment: oh, and for crunchy, you may want a longer time at lower heat to drive off the moisture